# Can't start up Google Cloud phpMyAdmin page?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up the phpMyAdmin page for Google Cloud using the following link which I followed 100% on this website: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine When I try to run the php server to see if it is up and running, I do the following:

```
C02Q202LG8WL:phpMyAdmin user$ appcfg.py update .
01:26 AM Application: database-140707; version: 2
01:26 AM Host: appengine.google.com
01:26 AM Starting update of app: database-140707, module: phpmyadmindb, version: 2
01:26 AM Getting current resource limits.
01:26 AM Scanning files on local disk.
01:26 AM Scanned 500 files.
01:26 AM Scanned 1000 files.
01:26 AM Scanned 1500 files.
01:26 AM Scanned 2000 files.
01:26 AM Cloning 1113 static files.
01:27 AM Rolling back the update.
Error 409: --- begin server output ---
No transaction is in progress.
--- end server output ---
```

And we keep getting this `No transaction is in progress.` error. It prevents me from being able to load the localhost/phpmyadmin page. Any ideas why this is happening? If I try to roll back the changes for the transaction, I do:

```
C02Q202LG8WL:phpMyAdmin user$ /usr/local/google_appengine/appcfg.py rollback database-140707/
01:30 AM Application: database-140707
01:30 AM Host: appengine.google.com
01:30 AM Rolling back the update.
C02Q202LG8WL:phpMyAdmin user$ appcfg.py update .
01:30 AM Application: database-140707; version: 2
01:30 AM Host: appengine.google.com
01:30 AM Starting update of app: database-140707, module: phpmyadmindb, version: 2
01:30 AM Getting current resource limits.
01:30 AM Scanning files on local disk.
01:30 AM Scanned 500 files.
01:30 AM Scanned 1000 files.
01:30 AM Scanned 1500 files.
01:30 AM Scanned 2000 files.
    Error 409: --- begin server output ---
There is an operation pending for this application: AppLock held for "Updating engine_version_id='2' within engine_id='default'." acquired by <Insert User> at 2016-08-19 08:26:05.734255 GMT.  Please wait and try again or use 'appcfg rollback' to attempt to cleanly abort the current operation.
--- end server output ---
```

I can't seem to figure out why I can't start the phpMyAdmin on Google Cloud and I'm not sure why or where these errors are coming from. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

I actually got everything to deploy correctly. All I had to do was change the `app.yaml` from the module `phpmyadmindb` to `default`. Here is the `app.yaml` I created:

```
application: database-140707
service: default
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
version: 3

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  login: admin
```

config.inc.php:

```
<!-- [START all] -->
<?php
// [START_EXCLUDE silent]
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
// [END_EXCLUDE]
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 * http://www.question-defense.com/tools/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '<Blow Fish Generator>'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

// Change this to use the project and instance that you've created.
$host = '/cloudsql/<Cloud SQL Instance Name>';
$type = 'socket';

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = $host;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = $type;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */
/*
* Other settings
*/
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
// [END all]
```

php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_uname, getmypid"
```

Here is the successful output:

```
C02Q202LG8WL:phpMyAdmin schan$ appcfg.py update .
01:12 PM Application: database-140707; version: 3
01:12 PM Host: appengine.google.com
01:12 PM Starting update of app: database-140707, version: 3
01:12 PM Getting current resource limits.
01:12 PM Scanning files on local disk.
01:12 PM Scanned 500 files.
01:13 PM Scanned 1000 files.
01:13 PM Scanned 1500 files.
01:13 PM Scanned 2000 files.
01:13 PM Cloning 1113 static files.
01:13 PM Cloning 2276 application files.
01:13 PM Cloned 2000 files.
01:13 PM Uploading 3 files and blobs.
01:13 PM Uploaded 3 files and blobs.
01:13 PM Compilation starting.
01:13 PM Compilation completed.
01:13 PM Starting deployment.
01:13 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
01:13 PM Deployment successful.
01:13 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
01:13 PM Completed update of app: database-140707, version: 3
```

The problem now I am having is that the tutorial says to navigate to `https://phpmyadmindb-dot-database-140707.appspot.com/` to view if `phpmyadmin` is set up correctly. As I navigate there however, all I get is a screen that says `Hello World!` but no actual phpMyAdmin seems to be deployed. I tried to go to `https://phpmyadmindb-dot-database-140707.appspot.com/index.php` to see if that was created but it wasn't.  Would anyone happen to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs suggest your app has multiple service/modules - I see log references to a `phpmyadmindb` one and there's also the `default` module for any app. Maybe you just missed this step in the [Create app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine#create_appyaml) section of the tutorial:

> 3. If you are deploying phpMyAdmin as the first and only application in App Engine, change the value for service from `phpmyadmin` to
>      `default`.
>
> Normally, you would deploy phpMyAdmin as a service of an existing
>   application and provide a name for the service. However, if you
>   haven't yet deployed an application, then you are required to use the
>   service name "default". That's fine for the purposes of this tutorial
>   if you're just trying out phpMyAdmin on App Engine.

Personally I'd replace `first and only application in App Engine` with `first and only service of your application` in that paragraph. Anyways...

For multi-module apps you should **not** use the SDK utilities (`dev_appserver.py`, `appcfg.py`, etc) in the typical/often documented manner - by specifying the app's dir (`.` in your case). In other words don't leave these utilities decide for themselves which services to operate on (which may lead to unexpected results), instead get used to explicitly  specify them by the list of the respective service/module's `.yaml` files.

Many docs/tutorials weren't updated after the services support was introduced and still suggest specifying **the application** (by ID or by app dir) when using the SDK utilities - which is non-ambiguous only in single-module apps. Specifying **the services/modules** explicitly instead - by their respective `.yaml` files - remains non-ambiguous for **both** single and multi-services apps and is less tolerant to human errors. This is, BTW, the default for `dev_appserver.py` presently (SDK 1.9.40), but still not the default for `appcfg.py` (run them with `--help` to check the syntax).

Back to your case specifics...

Both the update and rollback errors indicates the attempts are for the `phpmyadmindb` module, but the 2nd error indicates a lock is held for an update of the `default` module. Try explicitly rolling back the update for the `default` module (after you execute that quoted step if indeed you missed it), hopefully that will release the lock and allow subsequent deployments.

Also check the proper service/module names are present in the `.yaml` files - easy to miss especially when creating new services and copy-paste-ing the files from existing modules. Such cases as well as changes to the service/module names can cause confusion for the SDK utilities and/or app/service/module deployments, should be done carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response. I got the server to deploy but the tutorial says to navigate to `https://phpmyadmindb-dot-database-140707.appspot.com/` to view if phpmyadmin is set up correctly. When I go there, I get is a screen that says `Hello World!` but no phpMyAdmin GUI seems to be deployed. I included my app.yaml and made sure that `config.inc.php` was pointing to the correct `$host` (the instance of CloudSQL I deployed). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm NULL at php. But since the module in your case is the default one after renaming it I'd expect the URL in question to become just https://database-140707.appspot.com‌​/ (i.e your app's default version of the default module) according to Routing via URL (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url).